# php5-intl install for debian: "Remove the following packages"?

Tags: php, debian, intl

install php5-intl (internationalization) is giving me a strange warning:

Remove the following packages:
1)      libapache2-mod-php5
2)      php5
3)      php5-cli
4)      php5-curl
5)      php5-geoip
6)      php5-memcache
7)      php5-memcached
8)      php5-mysql
9)      php5-xmlrpc
10)     php5-xsl

I am unsure whether this will in fact take place, or it is just part of the upgrade of php5-common (5.4.4-14+deb7u5 to  5.4.4-14+deb7u7)

Is php5-intl a safe install?

Comment: Debian 7.0 May 13, shipped PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u5. Currently (Feb 14) any php5 library updates require first php5 to be upgraded to PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u7

Answer (score 1):

Debian 7.0 May 13, shipped PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u5. Currently (Feb 14) any php5 library updates require first php5 to be upgraded to PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u7